# Basic R Function for loading in and cleansing stock data

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to perform the following task for all stock tickers I am loading in with "getSymbols." I have tried using lapply but the functions do not seem to be working.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols(c("XLF","VFH","XLI","VIS","RWO","IYR","VNQI","VGT","RYT","VPU","IDU"), src = "yahoo",from="2012-01-01" ) 

#NEED TO FIGURE OUT A FUNCTION FOR THIS
XLF = as.data.frame(XLF)
XLF$date = row.names(XLF)
XLI[,c("XLI.Open","XLI.High", "XLI.Low", "XLI.Adjusted")] = NULL
XLI["ticker"]="XLI"
XLI["industry"]="industrials"
colnames(XLI) <- c("date","close","volume","ticker","industry")
```

Comment: You didn't seem to actually try "lapply" here. What specifically wasn't working? What input do you want to this function and what do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 1):

Though you have mentioned close prices in your output, would recommend using
adjusted price column instead since it is adjusted for corporate actions such 
stock splits, dividends etc.

I have used a test industry vector, you need to replace them with actual values.

You can use `new.env` and `lapply` as follows:

```
library(quantmod)


tickerVec = c("XLF","VFH","XLI","VIS","RWO","IYR","VNQI","VGT","RYT","VPU","IDU")

#test industry vector, replace with actual sector names
industryVec = c("industrials","financials","materials","energy",
            "materials","energy","financials","technology","industrials","technology","energy")


startDt = as.Date("2012-01-01")

#create new data environment for storing all price timeseries

data.env = new.env()

getSymbols(tickerVec,env=data.env,src = "yahoo",from=startDt )      


#convert to list class for ease in manipulation

data.env.lst = as.list(data.env)

#create an anoynmous function to reshape timeseries into required shape

fn_modifyData = function(x) {

TS = data.env.lst[[x]]

#xts to data.frame
TS_DF = data.frame(date=as.Date(index(TS)),coredata(TS),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#retain only required columns
TS_DF = TS_DF[,c(1,5,6)]

TS_DF$ticker = tickerVec[x]
TS_DF$industry = industryVec[x]
colnames(TS_DF)  = c("date","close","volume","ticker","industry")
row.names(TS_DF) = NULL

return(TS_DF)

}
```

**Output:**

```
#apply function to all timeseries using lapply
outList = lapply(1:length(data.env.lst),function(z) fn_modifyData(z) )


head(outList[[1]])
#        date close    volume ticker    industry
#1 2012-01-03 13.34 103362000    XLF industrials
#2 2012-01-04 13.30  69833900    XLF industrials
#3 2012-01-05 13.48  89935300    XLF industrials
#4 2012-01-06 13.40  83878600    XLF industrials
#5 2012-01-09 13.47  69189600    XLF industrials
#6 2012-01-10 13.71  86035100    XLF industrials
head(outList[[11]])
#        date close volume ticker industry
#1 2012-01-03 50.55   6100    IDU   energy
#2 2012-01-04 50.41   2700    IDU   energy
#3 2012-01-05 50.83   1700    IDU   energy
#4 2012-01-06 50.82   7700    IDU   energy
#5 2012-01-09 51.25   1800    IDU   energy
#6 2012-01-10 51.71   5500    IDU   energy


#if you wish to combine all datasets 
outDF = do.call(rbind,outList)

head(outDF)
#        date close    volume ticker    industry
#1 2012-01-03 13.34 103362000    XLF industrials
#2 2012-01-04 13.30  69833900    XLF industrials
#3 2012-01-05 13.48  89935300    XLF industrials
#4 2012-01-06 13.40  83878600    XLF industrials
#5 2012-01-09 13.47  69189600    XLF industrials
#6 2012-01-10 13.71  86035100    XLF industrials
```